# onClick listener does not function - breakpoint cannot be reached

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I'm attempting to set an onclick listener to change out the background on a button after it has been clicked. My problem is when I set a breakpoint at it's onClick method it cannot be reached using the debugger. I beleive this may be a syntactical issue - but I've looked over it several times and cannot seem to spot how to resolve it.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

JavaNoob

### SOURCE SNIPPET:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == fav_up_btn) {
            fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn);
        }

    }
```

### SOURCE:

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyC0Te2pyooXzuyLaE6_SsFlITKCwjj55fI";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";

    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView3;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView4;

    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        fav_up_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn);

        fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == fav_up_btn) {
                    fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview3);
        youTubeThumbnailView3.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview4);
        youTubeThumbnailView4.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader
                .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {

        }

    }

}
```

### XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Throw &apos;Em Up"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />

                <selector>

                    <item
                        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                        android:state_focused="true"
                        android:state_pressed="false"/>

                    <item
                        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_dwn_btn"
                        android:state_focused="true"
                        android:state_pressed="true"/>

                    <item
                        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_dwn_btn"
                        android:state_focused="false"
                        android:state_pressed="true"/>

                    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fav_up_btn"/>
                </selector>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by DJ Generic  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by idconex  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by idconex  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp" >
            </View>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### RESULTS:

```
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idg2/com.idg.omv.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class selector
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class selector
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at com.idg.omv.Home.onCreate(Home.java:43)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    ... 11 more
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.selector
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-22 13:46:00.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21880):    ... 24 more
11-22 13:46:11.205: I/Process(21880): Sending signal. PID: 21880 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you set up the button or its click listener

Comment: Button fav_up_btn; and public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v == fav_up_btn) {
   fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn);
  }

Comment: Are you using xml to link the button to the `onClick()` method?  If so you should post the xml file.  Additionally, you didn't answer the inferred question from tyczj so I will explain a little more in detail.  In the posted code you never call `fav_up_btn = new Button(this);` nor do you call `fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(...);`.  If you are using xml to do this then post the xml otherwise no one will be able to help

Comment: Apologies - I updated my source to include it (it is still not working though)

Comment: @user3009687 does your other click method work?

Comment: No methods shown thus far have worked

Comment: @user3009687 - edited my answer after you've added the XML layout ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == fav_up_btn) {
            fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn);
        }
    }
});
```

Why do you have a condition in the listenner, it would make sense if you were using the same listenner for others buttons.
But In your case I don't see why would you need that.

Try like this, check your logcat also:

```
fav_up_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn);
fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn);
        Log.d("mylog","fav_up_btn is clicked");
    }
});
```

---

EDIT:

> A single button I'm trying to toggle on and off

```
fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn.getBackground().getConstantState()
                                    .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_up_btn).getConstantState());  
        //set the background                            
        fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn : R.drawable.fav_up_btn);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Great! and to do the opposite (set it from fav_dwn_btn back to fav_up_btn) I would do: fav_dwn_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fav_dwn_btn);
  fav_dwn_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {       
          fav_dwn_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_up_btn);
          
      } 


correct?

Comment: You have 2 different buttons or are you trying toggle using a single button?

Comment: a single button I'm trying to toggle on and off

Comment: @user3009687 This isn't the answer to the question - the exception was caused by the `<selector>` inside the XML layout, as I was describing in my answer, not because of the `OnClickListener` and the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your button defined in xml, add somewhere in onCreate() the code:

```
fav_up_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn);
```

Then set your click listener. If you don't have the button in xml, and you want to create it as in your updated code (fav_up_btn = new Button(this)), you need to add it to the layout later. If you have your layout defined in xml, add an id to it, if it's not there:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and then, to add button, you can do it like that:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

layout.addView(fav_up_btn);
```

or like that (with the way you create button in your code now):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

Button fav_up_btn = new Button(this);
fav_up_btn.setText(roomName);
fav_up_btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(fav_up_btn);
```

Remember in either case to set the click listener.

Comment: I attempted to implement your answer but got a force close error (see updated notes above)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your `OnClickListener` for the button of course ;-)

```
fav_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == fav_up_btn) {
            fav_up_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn);
        }
    }
});
```

You're comparing 2 `Objects` against each other as if they were primitive types using the `==` instead of the `equals` method of `Object`.

To check if it's the correct view clicked, you should compare the id of the view against the id from your xml layout like this:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.fav_up_btn)
```

Besides, the check if not needed, because you use an anonymous listener for each `Button`, so the other buttons won't ever be caught by this `OnClickListener`.

**EDIT:** I see you've changed your question (added your XML layout as well). This makes a difference of course - this part is not valid inside your XML layout file:

```
<selector>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_dwn_btn"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_dwn_btn"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fav_up_btn"/>
</selector>
```

A selector should reside inside the `drawable` folder instead and it should be referenced in your button's XML like this: `android:background="@drawable/mySelector"`.

**2nd EDIT:** Just to clarify the exception your seeing. When your `Activity` is started Android tries to "inflate" your XML layout - when it reaches the `<selector>` tag it tries to inflate it like the rest of the XML layout - the items inside the XML layout is views or widgets and so the inflater system crashes the app because it doesn't know how to handle a `<selector>` tag because it's not a view.

Comment: Great! and to do the opposite (set it from fav_dwn_btn back to fav_up_btn) I would do: fav_dwn_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fav_dwn_btn); fav_dwn_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { fav_dwn_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_up_btn); } correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so ;-)